# Is it well viewed to post a "question" that isn't really literally a question?

Tags: discussion

By "question" I mean as named by SO.

By question I mean that it has a closing question mark at the end.

I'm looking for the strictest answers, taking into account the rules, obviously.

[This "question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304263/be-more-friendly-to-hard-working-reviewers) raised my curiosity. And I did an edit suggestion, but I believe I was wrong because it changes the meaning meant by the OP.

Comment: If you have found something that you believe to be useful for the community - it's ok to post it. You should still use the question-and-answer format: post your discovery as a self-answered question. There's an old [Stack Overflow blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) about it.

Comment: This "question" seems... vague to the point of uselessness... some examples might help?

Comment: If you’re looking for the “stricter rules”, you’ll have to tell us what in your view “isn’t literally a question”. Most “questions” on the site are 1-2 paragraphs. Some begin with a sentencing having a question mark, some end with one, and some include nothing at all (“This program crashes every time...”). But most of them aren’t, in their totality, something you’d label a question in everyday speech. So please elaborate on what you mean and provide examples.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek there I added info to que question. [This is an example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304263/be-more-friendly-to-hard-working-reviewers). Thanks for commenting.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks for the comment. I clarified on that in the question. I mean it has a closing question mark at the end.

Comment: Its worth remembering meta works differently from a regular site, and main meta works slightly differently from per site metas. Meta here acts as a combination of a blog (for announcements), support site (for bug and feature requests), soap box (for issues we'd like to bring to the attention of the community) and such. A question also need not necessarily have a question mark, least in the SE title and post context. On MSE It just needs to be about an issue that affects the network

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the main sites, questions should be just that - questions.

On the meta sites - both Meta Stack Exchange here, and the per-site metas, you can also post feature requests, bug reports and discussion items.

It is customary to write these as questions, but it is not obligatory.

In the particular case you linked, that is a feature request. It does not need to be phrased as a question.

The edit you suggested, unfortunately, is wrong. The feature request is directed at Stack Exchange (the company). Your edit would change it into a request for the community. But it is not the community that determines the length of review suspensions - the community can only request that, it is the company that decides.
It could be phrased as "Should Stack Exchange be more friendly to hard-working reviewers". Personally, I do not believe that title change makes a difference, so I'd leave this one as it is.

Comment: I think the case I linked would be instead a discussion item (not a feature request). Or am I wrong?

Comment: It is possible for a post to be both; the categories are not mutually exclusive. In this particular case, I myself consider it a feature-request - it is asking for a change in the site's policies. The OP, however, used both tags, so they probably considered it to be both a feature request and a discussion item.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thanks for being so involved (I don't now if that's the way to say it :); English is not my mother language) with the site!